# Is schema necessary for JAXB usage?

Tags: jaxb2

I have an xml file which I want to unmarshal. It is a very simple file with very well defined structure. Do I still need a xml schema to use JAXB? If so what is the other option? What are the pros and cons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a schema isn't required. If this is a simple one time thing then the overhead of validating against one may not be worth it. It's up to you.

Comment: What if I have a collection. Say for example number of books. How do I convert it to java objects